# Python code is not running correctly to measure length of strings

Tags: python, printing, string-length

my python code is not running correctly, I wrote a code that could measure the length of strings, but when I entered an integer or float number the result was that he measured  the length of the number, which is not correct .

Here is my code :

```
def Names_to_length(Names):
    return(len(Names))

Names = (input("Enter = "))

if type(Names) == str :
    print("Sorry, integers don't have length")
else:
    print(Names_to_length(Names))
```

Can you help ?

Comment: you can check `isnumeric`  - as input will be always `str`

Comment: `input` returns a `str` whether you type in digits or non-digits. What did you want to happen?

Comment: what result do you get?

Answer (score 0):

input will return a `str` - you'll have to check if it's numeric / float. Here is one way of doing it:

```
def isfloat(num):
    try:
        float(num)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def Names_to_length(Names):
    return(len(Names))

Names = (input("Enter = "))

if Names.isnumeric() or isfloat(Names):
    print("Sorry, numbers don't have length")
else:
    print(Names_to_length(Names))
```

Comment: @BassemFawzy did it answer your question? if so, can you please upvote & accept?